How to force the scrollbars to ignore an image?
I have a web HTML page that is AxB in size, and it uses a transparent image that is 2Ax2B.
Then the scrollbars appear at 2Ax2B. How can I tell the scrollbars to ignore the image?
The image cannot be set as background since it keeps changing and it has to go on top.
I tried setting the size using CSS in the body/html tags, but they are ignored.
EDIT
This is the relevant content of my page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <style>
#lasttime { position: absolute; z-index: 1000; left: 0px; top: 20px; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; }
#basemap { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; pointer-events: none; }
#radardiv { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; z-index: 1000; overflow: hidden; }
#radar { top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; pointer-events: none; }
html, body { margin: 0; max-width: 840px; height: 720px; zoom: .885; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="radardiv">
    <img id="radar" src="https://luis.impa.br/meteor/radarimgs/radar001.png"></img>
  </div>
  <img src="https://luis.impa.br/meteor/radarimgs/basemap.jpg"></img>
 </body>
</html>


Your question isn't completely clear - please could you create a runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I also do not understand why it couldn't be a background to an element which goes on top and which has the AxB size. Can you explain this a bit more?

take a look at object-fit css prperty

@AHaworth Sorry, you are right. Code added. I did not try your suggestion on the top element + background image, because I constantly change the image. But, maybe...

@AHaworth Yes, your suggestion about the top element worked... but partially. If the page is zoomed (like in my code), the scrollbars appear half way.

@AHaworth Even worse, the thing flickers when changing the images with radar.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + image + ")";

@G-Cyrillus, yes, I need a object-fit: cover, but with the image positioned at the top-left.

Does it flicker because it's having to wait for the new image to load?

object-fit comes with object-position too , so top left can be set ;)

@G-Cyrillus Yes, that worked! object-fit: none; object-position: 0 0; If you want, write an answer and I will select it. Thanks!!

@AHaworth Probably. But that does not happen with the img node. At least in Firefox. The img node substitutes the image only after it is loaded.

Without a minimal reproducible example is hard to understand exactly what you want. If you want the image to fit an <img> tag that fills its container then use object-fit: cover, this automatically fills horizontally and vertically without stretching. If your <img> is already correctly sized and placed and you just want to get rid of scrolling then you can use overflow: hidden in the image container.
Edit:
As @Luis A. Florit (OP) commented, object-fit: none; object-position: 0 0 is what solved his problem, the first places the image at its original resolution (without resizing) and the latter positions it at the left top corner

The overflow: hidden is what is not working for me. Please see my edit. A working page is here: https://luis.impa.br/meteor/mapaRadar.html

object-fit: none; object-position: 0 0; solved the issue.

Ahh I see, for <img> tags the object-fit property is usually the culprit. I'll add your solution to the answer, glad you fixed your issue!
